# Models in React Three Fiber flicker and glitch, but work fine in Codesandbox and also work fine in pure Three.js

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I have been hunting this bug for dozens of hours now, but just cannot find it:

The following simple React component works perfectly in Codesandbox:

```
import React from 'react'
import { PresentationControls, Stage } from '@react-three/drei'
import { Canvas, useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import './styles.css'

export default function App() {
  const { scene } = useLoader(
    GLTFLoader,
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf'
  )
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <Stage>
        <PresentationControls>
          <primitive object={scene} />
        </PresentationControls>
      </Stage>
    </Canvas>
  )
}
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-grass-sp2nyt?file=/src/App.js).

But the exact same code, with the exact same package versions (I triple and quadruple checked package.json) installed on my machine, cause all kinds of errors:

- Flickering
- Frozen controls (can no longer drag the object)
- Occasional messages in the console "THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost."
- "Jumpy"/laggy behavior, i.e. controls are queued up
- Occasionally completely grey canvas. (And on Chrome mobile, almost always just a grey Canvas.)

On desktop, the same behavior in both, Chrome and Firefox. On Chrome mobile just the grey canvas. It happens regardless of whether I try it in-context in my own App, or whether I try it in Storybook.

I went so far to implement the same in Three.js plain, and that works fine, using the same models. Any hints on how to debug this? I have exhausted what I can think of using trial and error.

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "9.46.4",
    "@react-three/fiber": "8.10.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/three": "0.148.0",
    "five-server": "^0.1.8",
    "keycloak-js": "^20.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "three": "0.148.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.15",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json? Also, are you using nom or yarn?

Comment: Try to make sure there aren't any "^" characters in your version numbers. Also, copy package.json from codesandbox again and remove any charters before package version in both dependencies and devDependencies

Comment: Also, add a console log after the `useLoader` hook

Comment: All the packages that are in the package.json on Codesandbox are in my package.json as well, and also don't use the "^" in mine. I checked these more than five times ;-)

Comment: I now also tried to add a hook after useLoader like so: `useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useLoader has finished loading");
  }, [scene]);` and can see it is called only once when the site is initially rendered.

Comment: In devDeps, `webpack` does have the up pointing caret (^). I know that might not be it, but was just pointing this out.

Comment: Can you try building the app and then viewing to see if that behaves the same?

Comment: Ok, I did - I copied the sandbox to my local PC, and without any other changes ran "npm install", then "npm start" and the result is the exact same glitchy problem :-(

Comment: Ohhh, I found a way to (somewhat) reproduce this in Codesandbox. If you click on the "open in new page" icon in the Sandbox, it opens in a new page and there it fails to load, with an error in the console that I have also sometimes seen ("A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator."). Direct link to the fullscreen app: https://sp2nyt.csb.app/

Comment: It works on my system though :D

Comment: What OS and browser are you on? please don't say safari :(

Comment: Just give me a moment to try running it on my machine.

Comment: I'm running it on Ubuntu 22.04 (Firefox 108.0.2 and Chrome 109.0.5414.74) and Android (Chrome 109.0.5414.86). I am now thinking the problem is heavily dependent on the Canvas size. I also found that the problems are drastically less when I add the "<Stats/>" tag to the Canvas. (Obviously not practical in production.)

Comment: /o\ F me, well that makes more sense, 'cause I just tried it, works like a charm. I have about 100+ tabs open, I'm certain this has to do with the fact that you on ubuntu.

Comment: Can you try using the Suspense tag like so `<Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>`

Comment: `<Loader />` can be anything really, even `<></>`

Comment: Ugh, so it works on your machine - also with the controls working smoothly? Sadly, adding <Suspense fallback={null}> around the Canvas doesn't fix it for me. In fact, I already had that on my site because it fixed some other problems I've seen. But I tried it again in the sandbox to be sure: It doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: If you have any lazy loaded content that might use the React.Lazy api then wrapping with the Suspense component is a good idea.

Comment: Alright, I didn't think of trying that before, but my office PC has Windows and now I tried there: It doesn't have this problem. Both, Chrome and Edge display the sandbox site just fine. Also, this helped me find out: The problem on Android with the grey screen turned out to be a completely different issue (the 3D model URLs were not reachable from that device). So in the end, this narrows it all down to one thing: My local machine, probably the graphics driver. I don't know how I would have found that our without you confirming it works on your machine. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Most probably your GPU yes. 'cause I just came from testing it on firefox, both local and codesandbox worked fine. Btw, can you try this sandbox out. Same thing as yours, I just simplified the css. https://6bktqe.csb.app/

Comment: Thanks, that one works with the same glitches, but the canvas is also tiny now ;-)

Comment: Hey man, gotta try something right?

Answer (score 0):

For the record here the result of the whole discussion in the comments of the post:

- The error is exclusive to my specific machine (Ubuntu 22.04), but happens in all browsers.
- Sometimes the problem gets so bad that other apps on the same computer start having rendering issues.

This leads to the conclusion that the issue is my PC, not the code.
Most likely it has something to do with my graphics card or with xorg. My video card:

```
Intel CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
```

In conclusion, this is probably a linux video driver issue. I found no update and tested also with the xserver-xorg-video-intel uninstalled, with no change.